# How to set a default value for callback function?

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm learning about Javascript Callback Function, but I don't know how to set a default value to callback function.

```
 let mul = (num1,num2) =>{
    return num1*num2;
}


let cal = (num1,num2,cb) =>{    
    console.log(`The Answer is ${cb(num1,num2)}`)
}

cal(3,2,mul);
```

Here the code I tried to set a default value to callback function.

```
let sum = (num1,num2) =>{
    return num1+num2;
}

let mul = (num1 = 3,num2 = 2) =>{
    return num1*num2;
}


let cal = (num1,num2,cb) =>{    
    console.log(`The Answer is ${cb(num1,num2)}`)
}

cal(mul);
```

Instead of `cal(numberone,numbertwo,mul);`. Can I only call a function like this `cal(mul);`.

**Edit**

```
let testmul = (num1 = 3,num2 = 2) =>{
    let result = num1*num2;
    console.log(`${result}`);
}

testmul();
```

This is what I would like to do. If I doesn't put a number in function. The function will have a default value. But this time I want to try it with a Callback function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--a "callback function" is just a function, you set a default value like anything else. But your *first* call is to `cal` (not your callback function), and you're passing in a *first* argument of a function, while `cal` expects two numbers *then* a callback function. It would be `cal` that needs defaults, and even then, you can't change the *order* of the parameters, just their *values*.

Comment: I have edit my post to give you more information.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your question read more: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/javascript-conventions/how-to-create-default-parameters-for-functions/

You have to check if the last parameter is undefined and then manually fix all the other parameters before continuing in the code. This case is also valid for modern JavaScript(ES6/ES2015). The example shows you how to do that:

```
const example = function (param1, optParam, callback) {
  if (callback === undefined) {
    // only two parameters were passed, so the callback is actually in `optParam`
    callback = optParam;

    //give `optParam` a default value
    optParam = "and a default parameter";
  }
  callback(param1, optParam);
}

example("This is a necessary parameter", console.log);
example("This is a necessary parameter", "and an optional parameter", console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let DefaultCallback = (args) => {
  ... do stuff
}
```

then you can do like this:

```
function myFunc(param1, param2, callback = DefaultCallback){
  return param1;
  callback();
}
```

then if you don't provide a callback like `myFunc(2)` as you said, it will have the default values of the function defaultCallback and it works for other variables as well, if you want to define default function parameters